# dir() under R 4.3.1 cannot display the filename start by Chinese character

Tags: r

I just installed the R 4.3.1, when I run `dir()`, It cannot display the filename start with Chinese character. another problem is that when i use  `ggplot()` to  figure, it create the following information:

```
 Error in Cairo::Cairo(width, height, tf, "png", pointsize, bg, 
"transparent", : Graphics API version mismatch Traceback:
```

But there has no problem when I do the same things under R 4.2.3

Can any one give me some information?

Comment: Hi! Can you share the example file name?

Comment: I created a file in my working directory called `编程.r`. When I use `dir()`, it is there no problem. I tried it on 4.3.1 and 4.2.1

Comment: the files in my fold in R version 4.2.3
dir()
[23] "Visual Studio 2022"     [24] "WPS Cloud Files"  [25] "WPSDrive"                                                      
[26] "参会回执一.doc"         [27] "弹簧振子.pptx"                                                 
[28] "附件3 科研人员论文自查表.docx"          [29] "股权融资规模(Wind统计).xlsx"                                   
[30] "骨干教师表.docx"      

the files in the same fold in R version 4.3.1
 dir() 
[23] "Visual Studio 2022"
[24] "WPS Cloud Files"
[25] "WPSDrive"

all files start with Chinese character donnt displayed